# MySQL joining tables complete confusion

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, count, left-join

I'll try and explain this as clearly as I can without confusing myself even further...

2 tables: "Products" and "Brands". Products have a unique id of "strId" and brands "intId".

I'm attempting to display a dropdown of available brands by checking the products 'in stock' in the products table; it's the next part I can't get right... count the corresponding products, so I can display like so:-

Brand 1 (4 products in stock), Brand 2 (12 products in stock), Brand 3 (9 products in stock) etc.

```
public function test()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('products p');
    $this->db->join('brands b', 'p.my_brand = b.my_brand', 'right');
    $this->db->join("(SELECT COUNT(strId) AS count_strId, strId FROM products WHERE in_stock = 'yes' GROUP BY strId) ij", "p.strId = ij.strId", "left");
    $this->db->where('p.in_stock', 'yes');
    $this->db->group_by('b.intId');
    $this->db->order_by('b.my_brand');
    $query = $this->db->get('');
    return $query->result();
}
```

I really can't seem to get the right combination of joins in this query - any guidance anyone? Much appreciated!

Comment: Please show the schemas for both tables.

Comment: Try the following: `$this->db->join("(SELECT COUNT(strId) AS count_strId, strId FROM products WHERE in_stock = 'yes' GROUP BY strId) ij", "p.strId = ij.strId", "inner");`